# How can I limit apache2's resources?

Tags: php, linux, apache2, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I have a very slow home server (raspberry pi) with 700 MHz CPU. When I develop some sites, it sometimes happens that I input a large (5 MB) .jpg file into an image resizer (`imagecreatefromjpeg()`, `imagecreatetruecolor()`, `imagecopy()`) which causes the server to hang.

I'd say it's processing the file, but even when I wait for minutes, it never ends.

The problem is that I cannot even access the shell to stop/restart apache2; the only solution is to power off the server completely.

I was wondering whether there's any way to limit HW resources for apache2; for example if I could limit only 80% CPU usage for it, maybe I could still access the shell and stop it.

I tried setting the timeout and max_execution_time directives, but they don't seem to stop apache2 from working infinitely and freezing the server.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can limit the cpu usage of apache from its own settings.

You can try using a separate app like cpulimit (see: [how-to](http://www.debianadmin.com/cpulimit-limit-the-cpu-usage-of-a-process.html)):

```
$ sudo apt-get install cpulimit
$ man cpulimit
```

You can also try these to optimize the overall performance of your server.

- Edit your /etc/apache2/apache2.conf and use these values:

  ```
  <IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
      StartServers          2
      MinSpareServers       2
      MaxSpareServers       3
      MaxClients           50
      MaxRequestsPerChild   0
  </IfModule>
  ```
- Expand your swap in /etc/dphys-swapfile set:

  ```
  CONF_SWAPSIZE=512
  ```

  Then run:

  ```
  $ sudo dphys-swapfile setup
  $ sudo dphys-swapfile swapon
  ```
- Overclock your raspberry (it's safer than it sounds) here:

  ```
  $ sudo raspi-config
  ```

  I use it at 950MHz. There is a higher option (1000MHz), but some people on the forum complained about SD corruption with that one.
- You can also set the graphic memory to 16 in raspi-config **memory_split** if you do not use the graphical interface.

Answer (score -1):

You can install apache-mod_ratelimit. Also, see [Control Apache with httpd.conf](http://htaccess.wordpress.com/2010/03/13/control-apache-cpu-memory-and-processes-with-httpd-conf/).

Comment: Apache mod_ratelimit is for bandwidth rate limiting of clients. (see: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ratelimit.html)

Comment: Also the RLimitCPU Directive (see: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/core.html#rlimitcpu) limits cpu time in seconds that a child process can use. It does not set a cpu limit for that process, but could still be usefull in the above case.